# Ideas for communicate N systems that uses ROS. (Example inside)

Tags: ros, communication

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, this is the situation:

let supose we all live in a small town where everyone has an autonomous car using ROS.. :D

Now, we want to enable V2X communication in our vehicles (vehicle-to-vehicle and vehicle-to-infrastructure) in order to stablish an intelligent transportation system, ITS.

questions are:

¿How to communicate N ROS systems between themselves in a intermitent wireless network?
¿How to communicate ROS systems through a Non-ROS System at Infrastructure*?

I know this is a very wide question, but I want to know if there is a proposed architecture for systems like this.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Non-ROS system could be, for example, a web server for traffic info or a intersection manager, etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49776/ideas-for-communicate-n-systems-that-uses-ros.-(example-inside)/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2012-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For multiple ROS systems there is [multimaster](http://ros.org/wiki/multimaster), although I don't know the state of that package.

Communications through non-ROS systems is obviously dependent on the non-ROS system.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2012-12-05**:
I've read about multimaster, but it is in current development. And the Non-ROS system could be a web server.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-05**:
Everything custom, you'll have to implement. Web server could mean anything. For the client site there is http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbridge You might be able to use that.